# Not getting test case results(passed/failed/blocked) from TestSuite using TFS API

Tags: c#, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to get test case results(passed/failed/blocked) from TestSuite under a test plan.

Using below code to do this.

```
  public List<ScoreBoard> GetTestStatistics(string teamProject, string selectedTestPlan)
    {
        // 1. Connect to TFS and Get Test Managemenet Service and Get all Test Plans
        string serverName = "*********";
        var server = new Uri(serverName);
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory
        .GetTeamProjectCollection(server);
        var service = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
        var testProject = service.GetTeamProject(teamProject);
        var plan = testProject.TestPlans.Query("SELECT * FROM TestPlan").Where(tp => tp.Name == selectedTestPlan).FirstOrDefault();
        List<ScoreBoard> scoreboards = new List<ScoreBoard>();
        var testSuits = new List<IStaticTestSuite>();
        if (plan.RootSuite != null)
        {
            testSuits.AddRange(TestSuiteHelper.GetTestSuiteRecursive(plan.RootSuite));
        }
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan() { Id = plan.Id, Name = plan.Name, TestSuites = testSuits };

        for (int i = 0; i < testPlan.TestSuites.Count; i++)
        {
            var ts = testPlan.TestSuites[i];
            var scoreboard = new ScoreBoard();
            scoreboard.TeamProject = teamProject;
            scoreboard.TestPlan = selectedTestPlan;
            scoreboard.Id = ts.Id;
            scoreboard.Title = ts.Title;
            scoreboard.State = ts.State.ToString();
            scoreboard.TestCaseCount = ts.TestCases.Count;

              int totalTestSteps = 0;
            List<string> testStepScores = new List<string>();
            foreach (var tc in ts.TestCases)
            {
                foreach (var a in tc.TestCase.Actions)
                {
                    totalTestSteps = totalTestSteps + 1;
                }                

                var testResults = testProject.TestResults.ByTestId(tc.TestCase.TestSuiteEntry.Id);
                foreach (var result in testResults)
                {


                    for (int actionIndex = 0; actionIndex < tc.TestCase.Actions.Count; actionIndex++)
                    {
                        var action = tc.TestCase.Actions[actionIndex];
                        if (!(action is ITestStep))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        var step = action as ITestStep;
                        var topIteration = result.Iterations.FirstOrDefault();
                        if (topIteration == null)
                            continue;

                        var test = topIteration.Actions[actionIndex];
                        testStepScores.Add(topIteration.Actions[actionIndex].Outcome.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
              scoreboard.TestStepCount = totalTestSteps;
            scoreboard.TestStepPassedCount = testStepScores.Where(tsp => tsp == "Passed").ToList().Count;
            scoreboard.TestStepFailedCount = testStepScores.Where(tsp => tsp == "Failed").ToList().Count;
            scoreboard.TestStepOutstandingCount = testStepScores.Where(tsp => tsp == "None").ToList().Count;
            scoreboards.Add(scoreboard);
        }
        return scoreboards;
    }
```

I am not getting correct result for passed test/Failed/Outstanding test count.
When I debugged into this, observed some property are showing message "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation."
Can I get how many test cases are passed under the test suite ? 
What could be the problem here?

Comment: The evaluation message means that object took to long to return property value, once this happens you will lose object info until you allow execution to proceed. Since TFS api supports deferred execution most likely it takes to long to query the result from server. Try writing to Trace or output results to console window, force execution on record sets by calling ToList() etc.